# Matplotlib bar chart been deleted

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

i am creating a sistem that creates bar charts to show how many products were sold every month, here is the code i use to create and plot the graphs

```
class barChart(figureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent, tipo='vendas'):
        fig, self.ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11,12), dpi=75)
        super().__init__(fig)
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.tipo = tipo
        self.ax.set(ylabel=self.tipo, xmargin=0.05, ymargin=0.05)
        self.ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0,12,1))
        self.ax.set_xticklabels(['jan', 'fev', 'mar', 'abr', 'mai', 'jun', 'jul', 'ago', 'set', 'out', 'nov', 'dez'])
        if self.tipo == 'vendas':
            self.ax.set(yticks=np.arange(0, 51, 5), yticklabels=np.arange(0, 101, 10), ylabel='vendas')
        elif self.tipo == 'faturamento':
            self.ax.set(yticks=np.arange(0, 51, 5), yticklabels=np.arange(0, 1001, 100), ylabel='faturamento')


        self.ax.grid(False)
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 260)
    
    def plot(self, produto, vendas):
        self.ax.cla()
        x = np.arange(12)
        if self.tipo == 'vendas':
            data = list(map(lambda x: x/2, vendas))
        elif self.tipo == 'faturamento':
            data = list(map(lambda x: x/20, vendas))
        bars = self.ax.bar(x, data, 0.8, color='blue')
        self.ax.bar_label(bars, vendas)

        self.ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0,12,1))
        self.ax.set_xticklabels(['jan', 'fev', 'mar', 'abr', 'mai', 'jun', 'jul', 'ago', 'set', 'out', 'nov', 'dez'])

        if self.tipo == 'vendas':
            self.ax.set(yticks=np.arange(0, 51, 5), yticklabels=np.arange(0, 101, 10), title=f'Vendas "{produto}"', ylabel='vendas')
        elif self.tipo == 'faturamento':
            self.ax.set(yticks=np.arange(0, 51, 5), yticklabels=np.arange(0, 1001, 100), title=f'Faturamento "{produto}"', ylabel='faturamento')

        
        self.draw()
```

but after updating it 6 times i get this error
`RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type barChart has been deleted`
how can i fix it?

Comment: After updating *how*? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: You probably need to store the resulting `barChart` object into a global variable (or as a class variable into another permanent object). Python's garbage collector removes objects that aren't referenced anywhere.  And maybe you also need `fig` as a class variable, similar to `self.ax`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.